# Retrieve and insert value from one table to another at the same time

Tags: c#, sql-server, shopping-cart

I am developing shopping cart for my project and i'm having trouble on how to retrieve orderid and insert into another table.

I have two tables in sql server

```
Order
orderid (PK) | date| orderstatus| name| shippingaddress| contactnumber| totalprice| customerid|

Order_book
orderid (PK) | ISBN (PK)| quantity
```

I wanted to retrieve orderid from order table and insert it into order_book, whenever order is submitted to the database, orderid in order table is an identity int with increment of 1.

what are the best options to retrieve and insert at the same time from one table to another using c#?

Thanks.

codes::

```
protected void checkout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SQLInjection sql = new SQLInjection();
    String name;
    String address; 
    int contactnumber;
    if (newaddresspanel.Visible == true)
    {
       name = sql.SafeSqlLiteral(NameLabel.Text, 2);
       address = Address1.Text + " " + Address2.Text + "," + PostalCode.Text + "," + State.SelectedItem.Value;
       contactnumber =  int.Parse(Telephone1.SelectedItem.Value) + int.Parse(Telephone2.Text);
       insertDetails(name, address, contactnumber);
    }
    else if (defaultaddresspanel.Visible)
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BookWormDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);//connect to database
        SqlCommand bindDetails = new SqlCommand("SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, TELEPHONE_NUMBER FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMERID = @username", myConnection);

        bindDetails.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        bindDetails.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = bindDetails.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                name = reader["NAME"].ToString();
                address = reader["ADDRESS"].ToString();
                contactnumber = int.Parse(reader["TELEPHONE_NUMBER"].ToString());
                insertDetails(name, address, contactnumber);

                }
            reader.Dispose();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {


        }
    }
    try
    {
        cart = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"];
        foreach (DataRow dr in cart.Rows)
        {
            int isbn = int.Parse(dr["ISBN"].ToString());
            int quantity = int.Parse(dr["quantity"].ToString());
            insertOrderbook(isbn, quantity);
        }


    }

    catch (Exception ae)
    {

        Response.Write(ae.Message);

    }
```

Insert orderbook : "Which failed"

```
protected void insertOrderbook(int isbn, int quantity)
{

    int orderid;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BookWormDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);//connect to database
    SqlCommand orderId = new SqlCommand("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() FROM ORDERBOOK", myConnection);


    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        orderid = int.Parse(orderId.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            SqlCommand insertOrderBook = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ORDERBOOK_BOOK (ISBN, ORDERID, QUANTITY) VALUES (@isbn, @orderid, @quantity)", myConnection);

            insertOrderBook.Parameters.Add("@isbn", SqlDbType.Int);
            insertOrderBook.Parameters["@isbn"].Value = isbn;

            insertOrderBook.Parameters.Add("@orderid", SqlDbType.Int);
            insertOrderBook.Parameters["@orderid"].Value = orderid;

            insertOrderBook.Parameters.Add("@quantity", SqlDbType.Int);
            insertOrderBook.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = quantity;

            insertOrderBook.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
        }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        Response.Write(se.Message);
    }
}
```

insert order details ::

```
protected void insertDetails(string name, string address, int contactnumber)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BookWormDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);//connect to database
    SqlCommand orderDetails = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ORDERBOOK (DATE, ORDERSTATUS, TOTALPRICE, SHIPPING_ADD, CUSTOMERID, NAME, CONTACTNUMBER) VALUES (@date, @orderstatus, @totalprice, @shippingadd, @username, @name, @contactnumber)", myConnection);
    orderDetails.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    orderDetails.Parameters["@date"].Value = getTime();

    orderDetails.Parameters.Add("@orderstatus", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    orderDetails.Parameters["@orderstatus"].Value = "Order Processing";

    orderDetails.Parameters.Add("@totalprice", SqlDbType.Decimal);
    orderDetails.Parameters["@totalprice"].Value = totalPrice;

    orderDetails.Parameters.Add("@shippingadd", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    orderDetails.Parameters["@shippingadd"].Value = address;

    orderDetails.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    orderDetails.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;

    orderDetails.Parameters.Add("@contactnumber", SqlDbType.Int);
    orderDetails.Parameters["@contactnumber"].Value = contactnumber;

    orderDetails.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    orderDetails.Parameters["@username"].Value = username;

    try {
        myConnection.Open();
        orderDetails.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();

    }
    catch ( SqlException se)
    {


    }
}
```

Error: input string was not in correct format

I tried to debug it, somehow, orderid shows 0

Comment: How is the order submitted to the database currently?

Comment: I'm now using "select orderid from order where customerid=username, date=date" and "insert into order_book (isbn, quantity, orderid) values isbn, quantity, orderid"; 
This happened at the same time, but somehow there is an error. 
Sorry, i'm kinda a new in programming. Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you're using as well as the error message you receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this select

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() FROM ORDERBOOK
```

What you should do is add an output parameter (let's say, @orderBookId) to your order book insert SP, and on it, right after the insert, you should do

```
SELECT @orderBookId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

notice there is no FROM clause, and be sure to add the parameter on your C# code, as an output parameter.

Then, when inserting the details, simply add @orderBookId as an input parameter and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to retrieve the newly created orderId when you insert an order and then put that ID in order_book.

To retrieve the last created value, use [`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) immediately after you inserted the item in the orders table. This will give you the orderId to insert into order_book.